# Many SocketTimeoutExceptions recently with Google Calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a Java application that updates student timetable calendars for our university. It has been running without any significant issues for the past few years.

I have not made any changes to the application but recently I am seeing many SocketTimeoutExceptions that were never an issue before.

Is there some change to the underlying systems that I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when HTTP requests time out, as you mentioned there are no changes in the application but there are certain things that may be generating these requests time out, (just as an example) maybe the load has increased or there are API calls made simultaneously per user/sec.

A possible solution is to increase the read timeouts.

```java
private HttpRequestInitializer setHttpTimeout(final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer) {
  return new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
      requestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
      httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes connect timeout
      httpRequest.setReadTimeout(3 * 60000);  // 3 minutes read timeout
    }
  };

GoogleCredential credential = ....

final Analytics analytics = Analytics.builder(new NetHttpTransport(), jsonFactory, setHttpTimeout(credential)).build();
```

**Reference:**

[Timeouts and Errors](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors)

Comment: Thanks Lorena, I found that same information when researching the topic. But this seems to fix the symptom and not the real problem. There has been no extra load or api calls per second on our side. the application has worked just fine for years. The real question is what has changed on the Google end. I can make this change but it just covers over the issue. What am I meant to set the new timeout to? Is is just trial and error until it works properly again?

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get? Based on the Calendar API information at https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors once there is a problem with Calendar API, it returns two levels of error information: HTTP error codes and messages in the header and JSON object in the response body with additional details that can help you determine how to handle the error.

Comment: Hi @LorenaGomez I am using the Java Calendar API libraries, the error being received is "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" but just to be clear, I don't want to make any changes to this application. This application is running in production and relied upon. It has been working just fine for years. If these errors are occurring now that indicates something changed on the Google end. I created this post to see if any others are reporting the same issues